# Словообразование слова "прочитал"

Tags: словообразование

Как образовано и с помощью чего образовано слово "прочитал"?

У меня три варианта:

1. Приставочный
2. Приставочно-суффиксальный
3. Суффиксальный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**прочитать** - от "читать" с помощью приставки ПРО-. Значит, приставочный.

Comment: А суффикс "л" не учитывается? А исходное слово не "прочитать", а "прочитал".

Comment: Прочитал - форма  прошедшего времени от начальной (инфинитива) прочитать. Л - суффикс ФОРМООБРАЗУЮЩИЙ, в словообразовании роли не играет и не учитывается, только при морфемном разборе выделяется.

Comment: Пишите:Прочитал-от читал с помощью приставки ПРО-